# Not able to understand exact information in the sentence

Tags: meaning

"There is simply far too much traffic, ~"

What is the meaning of this sentence. I cannot understand it.

Comment: This is far to general to get a good answer I suggest asking something more specific. Like asking what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

***[Far](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far)*** (adverb) is used  meaning:

> very much:
>
> - This ​car is far ​better than ​our ​old one.
> - It ​cost far more (​money) than I could ​afford.
> - He ​loses his ​temper far too often.

*Far too much traffic*   means "much more traffic" (than you probably  expected)

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The adverb "simply" is an intensifier. Intensifiers add emphasis, but do not change the meaning. Intensifiers include words such as very, extremely, so, quite, just...